# What is the formal definition of randomness?

Tags: random

What is the formal definition of mathematical randomness? For example, if one were to prove that a random number generator is random, how would one go about constructing a proof?

Comment: The concept of randomness is not in the realm of mathematics and there is little random about random variables or random number generators. You have to look into (meta-)physics/philosophy/ontology for that. And check-out https://www.random.org/ for random bits supposedly generated based on atmospheric noise.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking  for. Please add it as an answer so I can rep you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Random number generator is not actually a random number its actually pseudo random.Because you have an algorithm written to produce that number hence the randomness is a bit compromised in this fact..